# How to rotate "Earth" by touching with GLES20 (Android)?

Tags: java, android, 3d, rotation, global

Yesterday I tried to solve a Problem I had the entire Day and it is still unsolved. I searched for every combinations of words I could imagine to find solutions on Google etc. But without success. :(

The Problem consists of following idea:
I started programming GLES20 (Not GLES10!) on Android. There are many other ways how to compute matrixes and objects. So there aren't any methods like "Pop" or "push" Matrix.
I want to rotate a globe/sphere only by touching and moving my fingers. Touching functions etc works fine but the rotation itself never does. Everytime I first rotate by x-axis and then rotating by y-axis the rotation is still computed by local space axis of the object and Not two global axis. This happens whatever I do... :/
There are some people searching the solution for the Same Problem, but mostly GLES10 or completly different programming languages, never GLES20 and Java.

I will also post some Code parts later, when I get access to a Computer.
perhaps someone already understands what my Problem is.

Thank you so much! :)
Chrise

Answer (score 0):

In OpenGL ES 2.0 there aren't any of the matrix functions and you're supposed to take care of your own matrices. So, for pushing and popping matrices what you need to do is when you're drawing you copy your matrix to a temporary one, do whatever transformation on it and pass the temporary matrix to the vertex shader.

Comment: so ths doesn't really fix the problem... :/ This image shows a good example: http://www.leadwerks.com/werkspace/uploads/monthly_07_2011/ccs-1-0-76797600-1310350245_thumb.png you could rotate the car by its local axes. But you also could rotate it on a globale axis.